# GSON: Custom deserialiser throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonNull

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have some JSON data where some fields can be null if they never had a value.

I have decided to create my own deserialiser to flatten some of the nested JSON data.

However, I noticed that when my deserialiser comes across a JSON Null it throws the following

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonNull
```

This never happened before when I used the default GSON deserialiser

```
public class ShopDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Shop> {
    @Override
    public Shop deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject root = json.getAsJsonObject();
        String shopName = root.get("name").getAsString();
        String description = root.get("description").getAsString();
        String openingTime = root.get("opening_time").getAsString();
        String contactEmail = root.get("contact_email").getAsString();
        String telNumber = root.get("tel_number").getAsString();
        String website = root.get("website").getAsString();
```

Basically one of the field values from the JSON can be null, however do I really need to do a null check for each field?

How does the default one go about ignoring it

**To say again: do I really need to do a null check for each field?**

MCVE

This link is a very small android program that replicates the issue

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b8uy179jo4yz2o7/AACbiWgLf0ZClZJpYS7KFFEBa?dl=0

here is the code major parts of the code with explanation

```
  String JsonBad = "{\"shops\":{\"url\":\"www.exmaple/20932\",\"name\":\"Some shop 1\",\"description\":\"really nice\",\"opening_time\":\"every day from 9am to 6pm\",\"entry_fee\":null}}";
        String JsonGood = "{\"shops\":{\"url\":\"www.exmaple/2092\",\"name\":\"Some shop 2\",\"description\":\"quite expensive\",\"opening_time\":\"every day from 9am to 6pm\",\"entry_fee\":\"£10\"}}";
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Shop.class, new ShopDeserializer()).create();
        Shop good = gson.fromJson(JsonGood, Shop.class);
        Shop bad = gson.fromJson(JsonBad, Shop.class);
```

There is two JSON strings. JSON bad has a field called entry_fee which is null but JSON good has it with a value of £10 (not null)

```
  private static class ShopDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Shop> {

        @Override
        public Shop deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            JsonObject root = json.getAsJsonObject().get("shops").getAsJsonObject();
            String urlToShowCall = root.get("url").getAsString();
            String shopName = root.get("name").getAsString();
            String description = root.get("description").getAsString();
            String openingTime = root.get("opening_time").getAsString();
            String entryFee = root.get("entry_fee").getAsString();

            return new Shop(urlToShowCall, shopName, description, openingTime, entryFee);
        }
    }
```

Above is my JsonDeserializer. When it gets to JSON bad it throws the following

```
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.test.gsonissue, PID: 5412
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.gsonissue/com.test.gsonissue.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonNull
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonNull
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsString(JsonElement.java:191)
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.test.gsonissue.MainActivity$ShopDeserializer.deserialize(MainActivity.java:57)
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.test.gsonissue.MainActivity$ShopDeserializer.deserialize(MainActivity.java:48)
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58)
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:814)
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:779)
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:728)
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:700)
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.test.gsonissue.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
11-03 16:33:20.049 5412-5412/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

However, just doing JSON good works fine.

Comment: Please provide an MCVE.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Provided a very small program that replicates the issue. There is a dropbox link to the android program but I also show the major parts

Comment: Yeah, thanks for that. So, yes, you'll need to use `isJsonNull` or alternatively use `toString` but I don't find that safe at all.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis no problem, thanks. I came across that answer, but the problem is, beyond the code I showed, there is much more JSON and I do not wish to have isJsonNull for each field but alas I have no choice :(

Comment: Then `toString` might be your answer. (In a ternary expression, the `isJsonNull` doesn't look that bad.)